# Maven local repository pointing wrong location

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, repository

In my Android project I've defined mavenLocal() as repository in the root build.gradle file. However, if I publish changes to mavenLocal these will not be recognized by my project. However, if I define the location explicitly the changes ARE found, proving that the changes are correctly published. So it seems like my mavelLocal is not pointing to the default location?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() // picks wrong location? 
        // maven { "C:/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/" } // mavenLocal fallback
        maven { url nexusRepositoryUrl }
        maven { url nexusSnapshotsUrl }
        maven { url nexusReleasesUrl }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? I'm working with several people in one project, so the fallback method isn't a solution. Of course I could use a variable user path, but that's not what I'm looking for:

```
maven { url System.getenv('USER_PATH') + "/.m2/repository/" }
```

I do not have a settings.xml file in /.m2 directory (which can be used to override the default maven local repository location). I could create one to solve the problem, but it feels unnecessary to change the 'default' location to the 'default' location.

So I'm specifically looking for the reason why the default implementation of mavenLocal() doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT**

This following might be either related or an unrelated problem / question: I've got some trouble with old caches of repositories not being replaced by new ones, so that might also be an issue in this case. I don't have much knowledge about how gradle caching works, so if someone could provide me a clear solution for this, then it might also solve the problem. I'm able to clear cache sometimes, but the problem keeps returning, and I need a permanent fix for it.

Caches seem to be temporarily updated after a combination of any of the following (not order specific, and haven't been able to find out which are exactly required to fix my problem):

- Android Studio > File > Invalidate caches & restart
- Remove mavenLocal definition in build.gradle > sync project > add mavenLocal definition > sync project
- Run > Clean Project > Rebuild project
- Install & run project on device